# UISegmentedControl под UINavigationbar в UITableviewController

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, swift3

Можно ли добавить UISegmentedControl под UINavigationbar в UITableviewController как на скриншоте?
Ключевая особенность использовать UITableviewController
[image]

Comment: Почему именно UITableviewController?

Comment: @VAndrJ Чтобы не переделывать текущую UITableviewController в UIViewController. Используя UIViewController знаю как реализовать.

Comment: Добавьте в Container view Ваш UITableviewController и ничего не нужно переделывать.

Comment: @VAndrJ Вариант конечно, но интересно всё же можно ли модифицировать TableViewController

Comment: Почему просто не сделать table view controller меньшим, и в ету пустоту дабавить UISegmentedControl.

Comment: @OrestMykha У меня опыта почти нет. Но разве TableViewController это не законченное view?

Comment: Можете сделать UIViewController и на нево добавить UITableViewController, тогда ви сможете виставить ево размер.

Comment: Насколько знаю, это уже private api. Даже в примерах у Apple подобное реализовано в UIViewController с UITableView.

Answer (score 0):

Я нашла решение в этой ветке на Objective-C:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30504503/how-to-add-the-uisegmentedcontrol-in-uinavigationbar

Переписала на Swift:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    let segmentTitles = ["All", "Not on This Iphone"]
    let segmentedControl = UISegmentedControl(items: segmentTitles)
    segmentedControl.addTarget(self, action: #selector(segmentedClicked), for: UIControlEvents.valueChanged)
    segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    if let navController = self.navigationController, let tableViewFrame = self.tableView?.frame {
        let topOffset = navController.navigationBar.frame.size.height + UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height

        let toolBar = UIToolbar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: topOffset, width: navController.navigationBar.frame.size.width, height: 80))
        toolBar.clipsToBounds = true
        let flexibleItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.flexibleSpace  , target: nil, action: nil)

        let segmentedControlItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: segmentedControl)
        toolBar.setItems([flexibleItem,segmentedControlItem,flexibleItem], animated: true)
        self.navigationController?.view.addSubview(toolBar)

        self.tableView?.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(topOffset,0, 0, 0 )

        self.tableView?.frame(forAlignmentRect: CGRect(x: tableViewFrame.origin.x, y: tableViewFrame.origin.y, width: tableViewFrame.size.width, height: tableViewFrame.size.height + UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height))
    }

}
func segmentedClicked(sender:UISegmentedControl) {
    print("set=\(sender.selectedSegmentIndex)")
}
```